# How to update the data in Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update some fields from firebase and the error I'm getting is:

> The method 'update' isn't defined for the type 'Stream'.

Because I have a collection within the doc and within doc one more collection. I have attached the firebase database photo.

I am trying to understand it and solve it as I'm very new to Flutter and trying to understand the concepts. Please help.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    
    final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('tripdetails')
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .collection("trips");

    **docUser.update({'tripname':'Mumbai'});**
  },
  child: const Text("Update"),
),
```

[image]

Comment: docUser.doc(docid).update({'tripname':'Mumbai'});
you need to provide the docid

Comment: The method 'doc' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.
It gives error. I made changes like this:
docUser.doc(user?.uid).update({'tripname':'Mumbai'});

Comment: I think, you need to add await 
//final docUser = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('tripdetails')
                        .doc(user?.uid)
                        .collection("trips");

Comment: W/Firestore(  759): (24.1.2) [WriteStream]: (1512f96) Stream closed with status: Status{code=NOT_FOUND, description=No document to update: projects/partnermain-2e004/databases/(default)/documents/tripdetails/VX2LerlvFXbx0GE5LBM2KawYbyi1/trips/VX2LerlvFXbx0GE5LBM2KawYbyi1, cause=null}.

Comment: It gives erro like that

Answer (score 0):

İ guess you have to give trips collection doc. Example:

`FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection('tripdetails').doc(user?.uid).collection("trips") .doc(id).update({'tripname':'Mumbai'});`

Comment: W/Firestore(  759): (24.1.2) [WriteStream]: (1512f96) Stream closed with status: Status{code=NOT_FOUND, description=No document to update: projects/partnermain-2e004/databases/(default)/documents/tripdetails/VX2LerlvFXbx0GE5LBM2KawYbyi1/trips/VX2LerlvFXbx0GE5LBM2KawYbyi1, cause=null}.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error

> ```
> No document to update:
>
> tripdetails/VX2LerlvFXbx0GE5LBM2KawYbyi1/trips/VX2LerlvFXbx0GE5LBM2KawYbyi1
> ```

Because the document path you are trying to update is incorrect.

From the details you can see, the path....

```
tripdetails/VX2LerlvFXbx0GE5LBM2KawYbyi1/trips/VX2LerlvFXbx0GE5LBM2KawYbyi1
```

Instead it should have been.

```
tripdetails/VX2LerlvFXbx0GE5LBM2KawYbyi1/trips/e7wRt6KXe3j10MKkL9s7
```

Mustafa's answer should work.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection('tripdetails').doc(user?.uid).collection("trips") .doc(docId).update({'tripname':'Mumbai'});
```

But you must know the `docId` here.